# updating variables with nested async tasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an IP scanning routine to find web servers on a LAN, then based on the results of this scan, I need to determine which IP address is the one I am looking for by running a second async task in the onPostExecute of the IP scanning routine.

The IP is hard coded at this stage but I will be using an Array to store the scan results and use the array to try each IP in sequence as soon as I get this core logic to work.

The first async task finishes like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {            
        progressBarServerScan.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(100));
        tvScanProgressText.setText("Server scan progress " + "100" + " %");

        //must try home dir, I hope all will be "home"...else must manage different folders
        // check for each system type
        String serverCheck = "http://192.168.0.12/home";

        new identifyServer().execute(serverCheck);

        if (systemNameScan!="Unknown"){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Found "+systemNameScan+" system at "+serverCheck,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

As you can see, it launches the second asyncTask which checks for key words in the HTTP response to indentify if each of the found IP addresses are the one I am looking for. The 2nd async taks ends like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Pattern HPPattern = Pattern.compile("Visit\\sthe\\sHewlett\\sPackard\\swebsite.*");
        Matcher mHP = HPPattern.matcher(result);

        if (mHP.find()) {
            systemNameScan = "Hewlett Packard";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"systemNameScan is: "+systemNameScan,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            systemNameScan = "Unknown";
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"systemNameScan is: "+systemNameScan,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //offer option to post the HTML page found to the developer
            // for analysis
        }
```

The issue I am facing is that the Toast msg of the calling routine executes before the one in the sub-routine, and the variable I am updating in the sub-routine is apparently not yet updated when I am testing for its contents in the if statement "if (systemNameScan!="Unknown"){...etc. The value of systemNameScan is null at that stage so my check is not working...

Can someone explain why the calling routine is proceeding before the second async task onPostExecute has fully completed? and more importantly, how can I better structure this IP scanning task and subsequent contents analysis of the web pages to avoid this timing issue?

I tried to move the checking routine to the 2nd async task but then I couldn't find a way to use the IP address that was passed to the async task as the variable "serverCheck" is not known to the 2nd Async task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 questions:

---

1) *Can someone explain why the calling routine is proceeding before the second async task onPostExecute has fully completed?*

Because the call

```
new identifyServer().execute(serverCheck);
```

only starts the identifyServer task.  This call returns after starting the task on a separate thread.  Thus, in the calling thread (i.e. the thread that is executing the onPostExecute method of the first task), the display of the Toast is the next code to execute.  As you observed, the timing is such that this sometimes will display before the 2nd task is complete.

---

2) *how can I better structure this IP scanning task and subsequent contents analysis of the web pages to avoid this timing issue?*

Moving the checking routine to the 2nd task was problematic, because as you stated: *the variable "serverCheck" is not known to the 2nd Async task.*  So you could make it known by saving it as an instance variable:

```
// Note I took the liberty of renaming this class to start with a
// capital letter.  This is a Java convention.
class IdentifyServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    private String serverCheck;
    public IdentifyServerTask(String IdentifyServerTask) {
        this.serverCheck = serverCheck;
    }
}
```

And now the serverCheck value is required to create an instance of the task:

```
IdentifyServerTask task2 = new IdentifyServerTask(serverCheck);
task.execute(serverCheck);
```

Comment: I tweaked it as follows and now it works: String systemNameScan;
        private String currentIP;
        public IdentifyServerTask(String IdentifyServerTask) {
            this.currentIP = serverCheck;
        } ----- Thanks !

Comment: I tweaked it as follows and it works: String systemNameScan;
        private String currentIP;
        public IdentifyServerTask(String IdentifyServerTask) {
            this.currentIP = serverCheck;